# Substrate frame V2 how to use pallet_timestamp

Tags: rust, substrate

Following the substrate tutorial and declared the pallet configuration as follows
In pallet `lib.rs`

```
use pallet_timestamp as timestamp;
```

```
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_timestamp::Config{
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
    }
```

Configuration in `Caego.toml`

```
pallet-timestamp = { version = '3.0', default-features = false}

std = [
    'codec/std',
    'frame-support/std',
    'frame-system/std',
    'sp-runtime/std',
    'pallet-timestamp/std',
    'log/std',
]
```

I need to get the timestamp using `pallet_timestamp`

```
#[pallet::call]
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {

        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn update_recoed(origin: OriginFor<T>, record: Vec<u8>) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
            let pallet_time = <timestamp::Module<T>>::get(); // Error
            Ok(().into())
        }
}
```

How to access the time in Substrate Pallet V2?

Comment: I have provided you a better answer to how to design your pallet to get the time, however, in general, what you have written above __should__ work... So can you provide the error message you got so we can also solve that problem for you too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use the pallet directly as you are showing, you should instead use one of the two traits made available by the pallet and loose coupling of the pallets.

The two traits I am mentioning can be found in the `pallet_timestamp` [source code](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_timestamp/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#impl-Time):

```
impl<T: Config> Time for Pallet<T> {
    type Moment = T::Moment;

    /// Before the first set of now with inherent the value returned is zero.
    fn now() -> Self::Moment {
        Self::now()
    }
}

/// Before the timestamp inherent is applied, it returns the time of previous block.
///
/// On genesis the time returned is not valid.
impl<T: Config> UnixTime for Pallet<T> {
    fn now() -> core::time::Duration {
        // now is duration since unix epoch in millisecond as documented in
        // `sp_timestamp::InherentDataProvider`.
        let now = Self::now();
        sp_std::if_std! {
            if now == T::Moment::zero() {
                log::error!(
                    target: "runtime::timestamp",
                    "`pallet_timestamp::UnixTime::now` is called at genesis, invalid value returned: 0",
                );
            }
        }
        core::time::Duration::from_millis(now.saturated_into::<u64>())
    }
}
```

To use this, you should do the following in your new pallet:

1. Update your config to have a new configuration which uses one of these traits. You do NOT need to tightly couple your pallet to `pallet_timestamp`:

```
use frame_support::traits::UnixTime;

#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
    type TimeProvider: UnixTime;
}
```

2. Then, anywhere in your pallet, you can call `T::TimeProvider::now()` to return the unix time in milliseconds as a u64.

```
let time: u64 = T::TimeProvider::now().as_secs();
```

3. Then for this to work, you need to plug the `pallet_timstamp` pallet as your "`TimeProvider`". You do that by configuring this when you `impl` your `my_pallet::Config`:

```
impl my_pallet::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type TimeProvider = pallet_timestamp::Pallet<Runtime>;
    // Or more easily just `Timestamp` assuming you used that name in `construct_runtime!`
}
```